# Why 1.2*3 returns 3.5999999999999996 and not 3.6 in python 3.7 ? For other cases it gives correct value but why in this question it doesn't return 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

```
>>> 1.2*3==3.6
False
>>> 1.2*3==3.6
False
>>> 1.2*3
3.5999999999999996
>>> 1.2*3
3.5999999999999996
>>> 3.5*4
14.0
>>> 1.2*4
4.8
>>> 1.2*2
2.4
```

Comment: In Python, you can use [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) if this behaviour is a problem for you.

Comment: FP can represent many values.  3.6 is not in that set.  The closest value it can represent is about 3.5999999999999996....